# CSRF Token Zend Framework and Webkit requests

Tags: php, zend-framework, csrf

I wrote a CSRF protection for my forms and added a hidden token. The post is send to the same action. So my `formAction`code looks like this:

```
if($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
    $token = $this->_getParam('token');
    if(isset($this->session->token) && 
       isset($cellarToken) && 
       $token == $this->session->token) {
         ......process form.......
    }
    else {
       error_log('possible CSRF attack');
    }
}
else {
    $this->session->token =  md5(uniqid(mt_rand(),true));
    $this->view->token = $this->session->token;
}
```

and in my view html I add:

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?= $this->token; ?>" name="token" />
```

This works for all major browsers but does make some problems in Webkit Browsers like Chrome, Safari. Here I get a second GET request to my contact in the background which generates a new token and thus the form is not valid....

Does anyone know where this second request is coming from? If it would be my own code there would be a second request in ALL browsers...

Regards

Comment: Could it be a favicon.ico request?

Comment: @TimFountain favicon.ico request wouldn't use the url mydomain.com/contactform would it?

Comment: No, if the extra request is going to the same page then there's something else going on. You could try opening the network tab in Chrome and then reloading the page, that will list all the requests the browser is making so that might give you some clues.

Comment: Check if the same error occurs when you use the [ZendFramework's Hash element](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.standardElements.html#zend.form.standardElements.hash)? And maybe this question helps [Zend CSRF protection token doesn't work in Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4106678/1157147).